# C# Unit Tests and MSTest 14.0 command-line options for Platform/Arch

Tags: c#, unit-testing, command-line-interface, mstest

According to [MSTest.exe cli Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) and running:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe' /help
```

there appears no way to specify architecture as you can do from Visual Studio's

> Test ==> Test Settings ==> Default Processor Architecture

meue. There is a /platform paramater, but it is used for publishing test results.

How do I specify x64 as the Platform/Architecture when running MSTest.exe on a set of C# Unit Tests? Something like:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe' /testcontainer:bin\Release\UnitTestCSharp.dll /platform:x64
```

The `/runconfig` option seems like it might be an option but I am not finding documentation on how to use it to specify the platform.

I should mention that I need x64 because I have a native 64 bit dll used by the C# unit tests.

Comment: In a `.runsettings` file specify `<TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>`. You can check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635153.aspx) to get more information about a `.runsettings` file.

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk Do you pass that to /runconfig or /testsettings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution came partially from @[Sergii Zhevzhyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606577/sergii-zhevzhyk). I had to use [VSTest.console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) instead of [MSTest.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx). Running VSTest in the following manner. I did not need the settings file.

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe' /Platform:x64 bin\Release\UnitTestCSharp.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, please use vstest.console.exe instead MSTest.exe. See here; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx rationale.